# Redirect multiple URLs to one SSL URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two URLs pointing to one app and I would like them all to be redirected to the SSL address with www (i.e `https://www.example1.com`)

I currently have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [nc,or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [nc,or]  # Causes problems
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com [nc,or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example2.com [nc]     # Causes problems
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example1.com$1 [R=301,nc]
```

The conditions for www URLs don't seem to redirect properly and the browsers complain as much.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you're redirecting www.example1.com to www.example1.com, for starters. That'll give you an infinite loop.

Comment: That makes sense. However, if I take that line out, www.example1.com doesn't redirect to `https://www.example1.com`. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most Apache SSL setups, your best bet is redirecting Apache traffic on a port other than 443 (SSL) to the SSL URL:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example1.com$1 [R=301,NC]
```

or, you can check for HTTPS this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example1.com$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar error. The browsers complain that the request will never complete.

Comment: Try it with [R=301,NC,L] so that further rules don't execute. If that doesn't work, your setup would seem to be somewhat unusual, and you'd need to troubleshoot further via the logs.

Comment: I think my troubles may have been due to the way my hosting is set up.